# Symfony - Value isn't inserted into the database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4, symfony-3.3

I added this code to current Entity, and made a Doctrine schema update:

```
/**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ftt_code", type="string", nullable=true)
  */
  private $fttCode;

  /**
     * @return string
  */
  public function getFttCode()
  {
      return $this->fttCode;
  }

  /**
     * @param string $fttCode
  */
  public function setFttCode($fttCode)
  {
    $this->fttCode = $fttCode;
  }
```

I also added this to a form builder:

```
 ->add('fttCode', TextType::class, ['label' => 'FTT Kód zóny', 'required' => false])
```

But when I insert a record into the db, this value is not inserted and it's null.

Does anyboby know where's the problem?

Edit:

Here's controller code

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $security = $this->get('app.be_security.service');
        if ($security->isAdmin() === false) {
            $providers = $security->getReferenceListByClass(Provider::class);
            if(count($providers) == 1) {
                $zone->setProvider($providers);
            }
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($zone);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('notice', $this->get('translator')->trans("forms.message.inserted"));
        if($zone->isStreetDefinedZones()) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('zone_edit', ["id" => $zone->getId()]);
        } else {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('zone_index');
        }
    }
```

Comment: cleared the cache?

Comment: Yeah, but still same issue

Comment: the code you posted is okay. but it's really hard to determine what is not. post some controller code, any modification you did to the form rendering if any etc.

Comment: Okay, i added code from cotroller.

Comment: when I said "cleared the cache" I meant `bin/console cache:clear`, not the browser cache (I say it just to be sure, no offense). if you did that, check the symfony profiler (I assume you work in a dev env) in the bottom and check if the value you entered was actually received in the request, in the form etc.

Comment: I can't use Profiler due to PHP version. But when i use var_dump on variable $em from controller, i can see there, that fttCode value is filled in.

Comment: @VláďaKuzněcov, it is hard to guess without seeing the full code. I was expecting to see $zone = $form->getData() to get the posted data.

Comment: It's not possible to show you $fotm->getData(), but i used $form->getData()->getFttCode() and got string(5) "ML444" 
So in the posted data this value is not null

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have it, add

> 'data_class' => YourEntity::class

to the options resolver in your form type.

Then replace

> $em->persist($zone);

with

> $em->persist($form->getData());